# How do I fix the deprecation warning that comes with pylab.pause?

Tags: python, matplotlib

A short python program to demonstrate a bug I keep running into:

```
import pylab
pylab.ion()
pylab.title('doom')
pylab.pause(0)
```

If I run it, it works fine, but I get this warning:

```
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backend_bases.py:2280: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Using default event loop until function specific to this GUI is implemented
```

If I remove the pause line, then I don't get the warning, but my plot ceases to exist as soon as the program finishes.

I should like an elegant way to get the behaviour without the warning. Can anyone help?

Comment: Just ignore it, that is part of some work that did not get fully fleshed out.

Comment: funny that it's still not "fully fleshed out" 3 years later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it has been [fixed in matplotlib](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/8185) thus updating the lib should work

```
pip install --upgrade matplotlib
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `warnings` module.
https://pymotw.com/2/warnings/

```
import warnings
..
..
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore",".*GUI is implemented.*")
```

This looks for the pattern 'Gui is implemented' in any warning being issued and ignores it but allows other warnings to be reported.

Comment: @user32882 Given that the warning relates to code that was never written, what is the alternative? If you have a solution, post it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [waitforbuttonpress](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.waitforbuttonpress) should do what you want. Just replce the `pause` with `pylab.waitforbuttonpress(timeout=-1)`.

Comment: thanks, but I still get the warning, and the behaviour changes

Comment: @JohnLawrenceAspden That's odd. What backend are you using?

Comment: No idea, whatever you get with sudo apt-get install in ubuntu 13.04. Don't go to too much trouble on my account, I've decided I don't actually care and this is one of those things that will go away on its own one day.